# Calculate Covariance without Access to Original Input Values

Tags: statistics, covariance

Firstly, I apologise if I get this notation wrong. I'm a software engineer much more than I am a mathematician.

I have the following variables, derived from an input set of $x$ and $y$ values. I do not have access to the original set of $x$ and $y$ values from which these were calculated.

$$n = count(each(x))$$
$$\sum_{} x = sum(x)$$
$$\sum_{} y = sum(y)$$
$$\sum_{} xy = sum(xy)$$
$$\bar{x} = mean(x)$$
$$\bar{y} = mean(y)$$

So essentially I know the means, I know the totals and I know the number of inputs, but I don't have the original $x$ and $y$ values (or rather, I'm trying to save CPU cycles by avoiding iterating over them again).

Is it possible to derive the covariance between $x$ and $y$ from these pre-computed values?

I'll assume that the formula for covariance here is:

$$
\frac{
  \sum_{} (x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})
}{n}
$$

I had a go at solving this myself but I came up short and this produced the wrong result. Here was my approach.

First I looked to expand the body of the summation as such:

$$
\frac{
  \sum_{} (\bar{x}\bar{y} - \bar{x}y - \bar{y}x + xy)
}{n}
$$

I then split the summation apart along the addition/subtraction lines:

$$
\frac{
  \sum_{} \bar{x}\bar{y} - \sum_{} \bar{x}y - \sum_{} \bar{y}x + \sum_{} xy
}{n}
$$

The given $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are effectively constants here, I extracted them from the body of the summation.

$$
\frac{
  \bar{x}\bar{y} - \bar{x}\sum_{} y - \bar{y}\sum_{} x + \sum_{} xy
}{n}
$$

At this stage the original covariance formula has been expanded into a form that only uses the variables I already have and does not rely on any individual $x$ or $y$, so I thought this should work. However when I plug in real values this doesn't work at all. Where have I gone wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OMG I think I just solved this purely through the process of writing it up and reviewing what I've written. Obviously I need to multiply the summation of $\bar{x}\bar{y}$ by $n$ when I expand the summation. This now seems to work as expected.

$$
\frac{
  n\bar{x}\bar{y} - \bar{x}\sum_{} y - \bar{y}\sum_{} x + \sum_{} xy
}{n}
$$